# Where can I find the Markdown syntax supported by StackEdit?

Tags: markdown, stackedit

StackEdit allows you to write documents by using Markdown. I would like to know if it supports all the formatting supported by the Stack Exchange sites including the table format supported by the Documentation Beta of Stack Overflow.

At the time that this question was posted I didn't found any question about the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the cursor at the bottom right corner, to extend a toolbar that includes the ? button:

[image: StackEdit Toolbar]

But there are several formats that are not included like spoilers and tables, so  the best could be to try the examples on https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/markdown